# .NET Uri: unexpected Uri using constructor to combine paths

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I'm using constructor:

public Uri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)

to append relative paths to an initial Uri.
Usually, everything works OK and the desired path is appended, but, in some cases, the final path is REPLACED.

For example, with this code:

```
new Uri(new Uri("http://localhost:3000/app/api/publicapi/NAS_0x5d65d971895edc438f465c17db6992698a52318d"), "Blocks")
```

I expected this result:

http://localhost:3000/app/api/publicapi/NAS_0x5d65d971895edc438f465c17db6992698a52318d/Blocks

But I get:

http://192.168.26.50:3000/app/api/publicapi/Blocks

What's wrong, here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the final slash so it's treating `NAS_0x5d65d971895edc438f465c17db6992698a52318d` as a resource not a path:

```
var existingUri =
    new Uri("http://localhost:3000/app/api/publicapi/NAS_0x5d65d971895edc438f465c17db6992698a52318d/");

new Uri(existingUri, "Blocks");
// returns: http://localhost:3000/app/api/publicapi/NAS_0x5d65d971895edc438f465c17db6992698a52318d/Blocks
```

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_):

> If the baseUri has relative parts (like /api), then the relative part
>   must be terminated with a slash, (like /api/), if the relative part of
>   baseUri is to be preserved in the constructed Uri.